# How to dispaly selected value in edit page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, select, drop-down-menu

How to dispaly selected value in edit page.
in my form i need to display selected value. it is not selecting the value which i selected and submitted. else it shows "please select Study material".

This is my `StudyMaterial model`

`class StudyMaterial < ActiveRecord::Base 
   TYPES = ['Question Paper', 'Book', 'Audio', 'Video']
   enum study_material_type: TYPES
end`

This is my 'form.html.erb'

`<select class=" required form-control" name="study_material[study_material_type]" id="study_material_study_material_type" data-validation="required" data-validation-error-msg="Select study material">
                  <option value="">Please select study material</option>
                  <option value="Question Paper">Question Paper</option>
                  <option value="Book">Book</option>
                  <option value="Audio">Audio</option>
                  <option value="Video">Video</option>
                </select>`

How to dispaly selected value in edit page.
I am getting this error when i click edit studymaterial page

[image]

Please help me to solve this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= form_for @study_material do |f| %>
    <%= f.select :study_material_type, StudyMaterial::TYPES.map{|v| [v,v]}, selected: f.object.try(:study_material_type) , required: true, include_blank: "Select" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: this is selecting on edit , but the problem is automatically it is selecting default option as 'question paper' as first option, instead of 'please select study material'.

Comment: that is ok, but i need the default as please select. any solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

I think, you look something like that:-

```
<%= form_for @study_material do |f| %>
    <%= f.select :study_material_type, StudyMaterial::TYPES, include_blank: "Please select study material", required: true %>
<% end %>
```

It will display selected value.